# get count of items with some property in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects as follow.

```
$scope.students = [{'isSelected': true},
    {'isSelected': true},
    {'isSelected': false},
    {'isSelected': true},
    {'isSelected': true},
]
```

How can i get the count items that have `isSelected` property set to `true` ?

#### UPDATE:

The problem is `$scope.students` is fetched from a REST api and simply looping over the $scope.students variable does not work as the variable is `undefined` until the request is completed, and so the loop code errors out saying `$scope.students is not defined`.

I tried using `$watch` but in that case i have to define the loop under the watch directive and it only works one time when $scope.students is defined, after that the loop does not work as $scope.students itself is not changing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add the following method to your controller. Variable `selectedStudentsCount` in your scope will keep number of all *selected students* (where `isSelected` is set to `true`).

Function counting *selected users* in `angular.forEach` will be executed only if `students`is not empty. Otherwise for *empty* `students` variable `selectedStudentsCount` will return `0`.

```
$scope.selectedStudentsCount = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.students, function(student){
        count += student.isSelected ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return count; 
}
```

Please note that `selectedStudentsCount` is a function so it will have to be called with `()` in your template e.g.

```
<h2>Total selected students: {{selectedStudentsCount()}}</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did something pretty similar, instead of returning the count, I updated the total number of selected students as a var within the function. and use the method with ng-click. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon after the parentheses on the function call, even in the template view!

Comment: need yours help on this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084738/count-object-based-on-status-and-shop-using-javascript

Answer (score 27):

There is another way to do this: the AngularJS filters. 
You can write this:

```
var selectedCount = $filter('filter')($scope.students, { isSelected: true }).length;
```

Answer (score 21):

You could also use javascript filter method (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
$scope.selectedStudentsCount = function() {
  return $scope.students.filter(function(obj){return obj.isSelected}).length;
}
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over AngularJS filters (other than being available without AngularJS, which this question isn't about)? Why use this rather than AngularJS filters?

Comment: No major advantages, just an alternative using standard js.

Comment: +1
And if you can afford ES6, you may want to use an arrow function like the cool kids do
`return $scope.students.filter((obj) => obj.isSelected).length;`