# How to count items inarray by attribute in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In my contrller.js I have array 'arr'

Like This :

```
$scope.arr = [
   {block: 0},
   {block: 1},
   {block: 1},
]
```

I want to count items with `block : 1` but not using `ng-repeat`?
I tried:

```
{{arr.lenght | filter:block == '1'}}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you've spelled `length` wrong

Comment: Check you Answer may be its works [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
{{ ( arr | filter: { block: 1 } ).length }}
```

`arr | filter: { block: 1 }` will return an array that matches your condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using filter

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Amount is {{(arr|amount)}}

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.arr = [
       {block: 0},
       {block: 1},
       {block: 1},
    ]
}

 myApp.filter("amount", function(){
    return function(array){     
        var amount = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
            if(array[i].block == 1)
                amount+= 1;
        }

        return amount;
    };
});
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/awtqdcoz/3/) of the example