# How to get the count of the Object with specific value in JSON in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json

Can anyone help me in getting the counts of the **Status** Field

From Below JSON I wanted to know how many filed with Status = Open and Closed and Assigned

How can get the values in Anular JS

Angular JS (Here I am getting the JSON value from URL and it contains below JSON Data

```
var app = angular.module('defectApp', ["ngTable"]);
app.controller('defectController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http({method: 'POST', url: '/angular/defect/defect.json'}).success(function(response) {
            $scope.post = response;

        })
    },
]);
```

JSON Data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 1,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Open",
      "severity": "1 - Urgent"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 2,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Open",
      "severity": "3 - High"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 3,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Assigned",
      "severity": "3 - High"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 4,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Closed",
      "severity": "4 - Medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "defect",
      "id": 5,
      "user-01": "John",
      "status": "Closed",
      "severity": "4 - Medium"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get count of items with some property in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array)

Comment: @manzapanza I have followed these kind of questions here in my JSON data there are so many fields present Is there a way a function should handle all this like Count of Status=Open and etc should result with the count value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Angular's `$filter` service.

```
var openCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Open'}).length,
    closedCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Closed'}).length,
    assignedCount = $filter('filter')(response.data, {status: 'Assigned'}).length;
```

The filter will reduce the array to just the objects with a particular status, then you can just count the number in the array.

Comment: Thanks it worked, Suppose if there are no values with Status = Assigned is there a way it will return as `0`

Comment: If there are no matches from the filter it should return an empty array, and thus the count will be 0.