# Counting occurrences of particular property value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know how i can count the number of occurences on an array of object like this one :

```
[
{id : 12,
 name : toto,
},
{id : 12,
 name : toto,
},
{id : 42,
 name : tutu,
},
{id : 12,
 name : toto,
},
]
```

in this case i would like to have a function who give me this :

```
getNbOccur(id){
//don't know...//

return occurs;
}
```

and if i give the id 12 i would like to have 3.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tryed to did this : 
        for (let userData of json) {
          let newUserData = new UserData()
          newUserData.id = userData.personId;
          newUserData.name = this.personsService.getPersonBy(userData.personId).text,
          count = count + 1,
          newUserData.val = count,
          data.push(newUserData);
        }
but it only count the number of turns into my for instruction... Without any distiction of id

Comment: Iterate and keep an object of id to count? Not sure what the issue is. Or if you just want for a single id just check the id and increment the counter when appropriate. It doesn't get much easier than this, btw.

Comment: Is this static data, or does it change during a session?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

A simple ES6 solution is using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the elements with matching id and, then, get the length of the filtered array:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 42, name: 'tutu'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
];

const id = 12;
const count = array.filter((obj) => obj.id === id).length;

console.log(count);
```

**Edit**: Another solution, that is more efficient (since it does not generate a new array), is the usage of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as [suggested by @YosvelQuintero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547504/counting-occurrences-of-particular-property-value-in-array-of-objects/45547593#comment78055276_45547593):

```js
const array = [
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 42, name: 'tutu'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
];

const id = 12;
const count = array.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.id === id ? ++acc : acc, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use filter for this since you don't need the new collection. Better to either iterate manually or via built-in and count.

Comment: Yeah,  I agree. We are generating a new array which items we don't really need. It's not an optimal solution for sure. If the array is never large, on the other hand, the performance difference is irrelevant, so it might be interesting having a one-liner like this.

Comment: I would use `reduce` like this: `array.reduce((a, c) => c.id === id ? ++a : a, 0);`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero It is indeed a better solution.

Comment: There is no `Array#reduce` solution (and several other possibilities) in the redirected as "duplicate": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array

Comment: Have a look at this ES6 solution, if the data is static then counts can be cached, or if data is dynamic then it handles that too. https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/j26s66m3/

Comment: @Xotic750 that solution was written about 4 years ago.. I think at that time there was no so intensive usage of `Array.prototype.reduce()` as of today..

Comment: need yours help on this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084738/count-object-based-on-status-and-shop-using-javascript

Answer (score 7):

You count

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'},
  {id: 42, name: 'tutu'},
  {id: 12, name: 'toto'}
]

function getNbOccur(id, arr) {
  var occurs = 0;
  
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if ( 'id' in arr[i] && arr[i].id === id ) occurs++;
  }

  return occurs;
}

console.log( getNbOccur(12, arr) )
```

Comment: need yours help on this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084738/count-object-based-on-status-and-shop-using-javascript