# How can I count the amount of objects with the same name in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array and trying to get count of objects with the same `name` property. How can I reach this? Maybe in modern "es6" way

```
let cars = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000'},
    {id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010'},
    {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014'} 
];
```

Comment: You could look into using the Array.reduce method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting occurrences of particular property value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547504/counting-occurrences-of-particular-property-value-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution for you:

```js
let cars = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mercedes", year: "2015" },
  { id: 2, name: "Mercedes", year: "2000" },
  { id: 3, name: "BMW", year: "2010" },
  { id: 4, name: "BMW", year: "2004" },
  { id: 5, name: "Volvo", year: "2012" },
  { id: 6, name: "Volvo", year: "2014" },
];

let numbers = cars.reduce((acc, child) => {
  if (!acc[child.name]) {
    acc[child.name] = 0;
  }
  acc[child.name]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let counterObj = {}

let cars = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000'},
    {id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010'},
    {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014'} 
];


for (property of cars){
    counterObj[property.name] = 1 + (counterObj[property.name] || 0)
}

console.log(counterObj)
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cars = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000'},
    {id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010'},
    {id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014'} 
];

let obj = {}

cars.forEach((item) => {
  //console.log(obj[item.name]) this return as undefined
  if (!obj[item.name]) {
    obj[item.name] = 1;
  } else {
    obj[item.name] += 1;
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `reduce` function, that would iterate over each object and adds one to the count

```js
let cars = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mercedes", year: "2015" },
  { id: 2, name: "Mercedes", year: "2000" },
  { id: 3, name: "BMW", year: "2010" },
  { id: 4, name: "BMW", year: "2004" },
  { id: 5, name: "Volvo", year: "2012" },
  { id: 6, name: "Volvo", year: "2014" }
];

let count = cars.reduce((acc, child) => {
  acc[child.name] = (acc[child.name] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cars = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mercedes", year: "2015" },
  { id: 2, name: "Mercedes", year: "2000" },
  { id: 3, name: "BMW", year: "2010" },
  { id: 4, name: "BMW", year: "2004" },
  { id: 5, name: "Volvo", year: "2012" },
  { id: 6, name: "Volvo", year: "2014" },
  { id: 7, name: "Volvo", year: "2012" },
  { id: 8, name: "Volvo", year: "2014" },
  { id: 9, name: "Volvo", year: "2012" }
];

let result = cars.reduce((acc, child, index) => {
    const indexFinded = acc.findIndex(el => el.name==child.name && el.year ==child.year);

    const result = {}

    if(indexFinded == -1) {
        result.name = child.name;
        result.year = child.year;
        result.qtd = 1;
        acc.push(result)
    } else {
        acc[indexFinded].qtd += 1
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```