# count same key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

orginal array:
................

```
[
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7e19e6b26621247a35cd"}
   }
]
```

new array: count same _id and put it in messageCount
.................

```
[
 {
  from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"},
  messageCount: 2
 },
 {
  from: {_id: "60dd7e19e6b26621247a35cd"},
  messageCount: 1
 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your attempt.

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547504/counting-occurrences-of-particular-property-value-in-array-of-objects

Comment: use `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.find` ...

Comment: @decpk please share code

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use reduce to solve this.

```js
const items = [
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7e19e6b26621247a35cd"}
   }
];

/**
 * Extracts the id from an item
 */
function getId(item){
    return item['from']['_id'];
}

// Previous is an empty array, given as second argument of the reduce function
// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
const result = items.reduce(function (previous, next) {
    // Get the id of the next item (or the current item in the iteration)
    const id = getId(next);
    // Looking for an existing item in the array
    // @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex
    const index = previous.findIndex(item => id === getId(item));

    if (index !== -1) {
        // If there is already an item with the same id, increment the message count
        previous[index]['messageCount'] += 1;
    } else {
        // If there is not an item, insert an new item with the message count of 1
        previous.push({
            ...next,
            messageCount: 1,
        });
    }

    return previous;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Sources:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array methods   I used `.forEach` loop with `.reduce` method ... Also to count the number of occurrences I created a simple array method ...

```
const array = [
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7c7950d9e01088e438e0"}
   },
   {
    from: {_id: "60dd7e19e6b26621247a35cd"}
   }
];

/*
  Creating an array mthod which can find the number of occurrences of the item passed as parameter in th array 
*/

Array.prototype.getItemCount = function(item) {
  let counts = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    let num = this[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1: 1;
  }
  return counts[item] || 0;
};


let result = [];

// Getting all id and storing it in a constant using array.reduce method
const allIds = array.reduce((acc,item)=> acc.concat(item.from._id),[]);

// filtering out unquie id's using forEach loop and terenary operator ( conditions )
let filtered_id = [];
allIds.forEach((id)=> {
   !filtered_id.includes(id) ? filtered_id.push(id) : null;
});

// Finally  pasting all the required data inside the required result ! 

filtered_id.forEach(id =>{
    result.push({
    from: { _id: id },
    messageCount :  allIds.getItemCount(id)
    });
});

console.log(result);
```