# How can i get the number of times a word is in an array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose i have an array of objects:

`const arrayOfItems = [{id: 1, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 2, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 3, title: "Pasta"}]`

How can i get the number of times **Pizza** is in the array? I am building a simple add to cart functionality in JS where i want to show how many pizza there is in the cart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting occurrences of particular property value in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547504/counting-occurrences-of-particular-property-value-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: have you done any research before asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arrayOfItems = [{id: 1, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 2, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 3, title: "Pasta"}]

const pizzaOccurrences = arrayOfItems.reduce((a,b) => a += b.title == "Pizza" ? 1 : 0, 0)

console.log(pizzaOccurrences)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to remove the items whose `title` property isn't `'Pizza'`, then get the length:

```js
const arrayOfItems = [{id: 1, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 2, title: "Pizza"}, {id: 3, title: "Pasta"}]

const pizzaOccurrences = arrayOfItems.filter(e => e.title == "Pizza").length

console.log(pizzaOccurrences)
```