# How do i check if an array have 2 or more same value and return false if it does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i have an array like:

```
[
{id:1,name:abc,age:12,primary:true}
{id:2,name:zyx,age:23,primary:true}
{id:3,name:hello,age:34, primary:false}
]
```

I this array I need to check if primary has more than 1 true or not if yes return false else return true

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get count of items with some property in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array.filter` to get a new array of primaries and check that array's `length`

```js
let arr = [
    {id:1,name:'abc',age:12,primary:true},
    {id:2,name:'zyx',age:23,primary:true},
    {id:3,name:'hello',age:34, primary:false}
]

let moreThanOnePrimary = arr.filter(x => x.primary).length >= 2;
console.log(moreThanOnePrimary);
let returnValue = !moreThanOnePrimary;
```

Comment: can u tell me what is the use of returnValue?

Comment: @AnujShakya just I thought you have to revert the condition because you want to return `false` when there are multiple primaries