# Iterate through an Array of Objects and calculate occurrences of certain values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

In my Vue/Nuxt app, I have an array that contains several objects in it (see below).

```
"Members" : [ {
    "Country" : "Spain",
    "Vote" : "For"
  }, {
    "Country" : "Italy",
    "Vote" : "For"
  },
  {
    "Country" : "Italy",
    "Vote" : "For"
  }, {
    "Country" : "Italy",
    "Vote" : "Against"
  }]
```

The "Country" values can be duplicate, as can be the "Vote" values.
What I'd like to have is **a new array of objects that has a unique list of countries, counting the total number of "For" and "Against" values**.

E.g., in the above example I'd need an Array that looks as follows:

```
[{
   "Country" : "Spain",
   "VoteFor": 1,
   "VoteAgainst": 0
},

{
   "Country": "Italy",
   "VoteFor": 2,
   "VoteAgainst": 1
}]
```

I was able to get a unique list of countries using the Set() object.

```
Members.forEach((Member) => {
        countrySet.add(Member.Country)
      })
```

However, I don't know how to continue from there.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How deeply did you research this?  Did you find this maybe?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array  How would you attempt to get beyond where you ended?  Are you familiar with `reduce`?

Comment: I spent around 2h on this issue, but my JS are not very advanced, so I'm sometimes struggling with the basics. However, the suggestion from Ori works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array to a Map. If a `Country` doesn't exist in the Map, set a new object for the country. Increment the relevant `Vote` in the object. Convert the Map to an array by using `Array.from()` on the Map's `.values()` iterator.

If you only have `For` and `Again` (abstain is not an option), you can convert the `if...else` to a simpler ternary.

```js
const members = [{"Country":"Spain","Vote":"For"},{"Country":"Italy","Vote":"For"},{"Country":"Italy","Vote":"For"},{"Country":"Italy","Vote":"Against"}]
    
const result = Array.from(
  members
    .reduce((acc, o) => {
      if(!acc.has(o.Country)) acc.set(o.Country, {
        Country: o.Country,
        VoteFor: 0,
        VoteAgainst: 0
      })
      
      const item = acc.get(o.Country)
      
      if(o.Vote === 'For') item.VoteFor += 1
      else if(o.Vote === 'Against') item.VoteAgainst += 1
      
      return acc
    }, new Map())
    .values()
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const members = [ 
  { "Country" : "Spain", "Vote" : "For" }, 
  { "Country" : "Italy", "Vote" : "For" },
  { "Country" : "Italy", "Vote" : "For" }, 
  { "Country" : "Italy", "Vote" : "Against" }
];

const res = [...
// iterate over members while updating a map of Country-Member pairs
members.reduce((membersMap, { Country, Vote }) => {
  // get member from map
  const member = membersMap.get(Country);
  // if it doesn't exist, add with initial Vote
  if(!member) membersMap.set(Country, {Country, [Vote]:1});
  // else update the vote count of the current category
  else member[Vote] = (member[Vote] || 0) + 1; 
  return membersMap;
}, new Map)
// return all the values of this map, i.e., the members objects with the counts
.values()];

console.log(res);
```