# How can I get the total number of truthy results of my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

can someone help me to find the number of stories with the category card?

My data looks something like this:

```
export const data = [
{
    id: "1",
    location: "Mexico",
    title: "Mexico",
    text: "Intro about Mexico",
    image: Mexique.png,
    stories: [
      {
        category: "card",
        title: "Yucatan",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "Mexico, ....",
      },
      {
        category: "route",
        title: "My route",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
   {
        category: "story",
        title: "My story",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Now I would like to know the total number of cards (stories with **category card**) that are displayed. I tried a lot of things, this is how my code looks like now but I don't get the nr of cards yet.

```
let nrOfCards = 0
data.map((card) => 
   card.stories.map((story) => {
      const storiesWithCategoryCard = story.category === 'card' 
      console.log(storiesWithCategoryCard)
})
```

In the console I now see a list of booleans. If the category is card it is true and otherwise false. How can I get the lenght of this list?
This didn't work:

```
nrOfCards = storiesWithCategoryCard.filter(Boolean).length
```

I hope someone can help my to find the last piece of my puzzle!

Comment: You can use `Array.reduce` to sum up, and `Array.some` to see if any category equals `card`, finally cast `some` to `Number` and this will make into 0 or 1,.. All together ->  `data.reduce((a,v) => a += Number(v.stories.some(s => s.category === 'card' )), 0);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get count of items with some property in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360256/get-count-of-items-with-some-property-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has multi `id` :

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    location: "Mexico",
    title: "Mexico",
    text: "Intro about Mexico",
    image: 'Mexique.png',
    stories: [
      {
        category: "card",
        title: "Yucatan",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "Mexico, ....",
      },
      {
        category: "route",
        title: "My route",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
   {
        category: "story",
        title: "My story",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    location: "Mexico1",
    title: "Mexico1",
    text: "Intro about Mexico1",
    image: 'Mexique.png',
    stories: [
      {
        category: "card",
        title: "Yucatan1",
        location: "Mexico1",
        text: "Mexico1, ....",
      },
      {
        category: "route",
        title: "My route1",
        location: "Mexico1",
        text: "....",
      },
   {
        category: "story",
        title: "My story1",
        location: "Mexico1",
        text: "....",
      },
    ],
  },
]
const totalStories = data.reduce((res, ele) => {
  let num = ele.stories.reduce((r, e) => e.category === "card" ? r+1 : r, 0)
  return res + num
}, 0)
console.log(totalStories)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same logic to determine if it's a 'card' in your filter callback as you do in your map callback. You'll just slightly improve the efficiency with short-circuit execution (using `.some()`):

This will get you the number of data items that contain at least one story with a category of 'card'. See below if you want different results - it was unclear from your original post what you were looking for.

```js
const data = [
{
    id: "1",
    location: "Mexico",
    title: "Mexico",
    text: "Intro about Mexico",
    image: 'Mexique.png',
    stories: [
      {
        category: "card",
        title: "Yucatan",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "Mexico, ....",
      },
      {
        category: "route",
        title: "My route",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
   {
        category: "story",
        title: "My story",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
    ],
  },
]

let storiesWithCategoryCard = data.filter(item => {
  return item.stories.some(story => story.category === 'card');
})

console.log(storiesWithCategoryCard.length)
```

If you want to get the number of stories with the category of 'card', using `.reduce()` would be a better option, like this:

```js
const data = [
{
    id: "1",
    location: "Mexico",
    title: "Mexico",
    text: "Intro about Mexico",
    image: 'Mexique.png',
    stories: [
      {
        category: "card",
        title: "Yucatan",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "Mexico, ....",
      },
      {
        category: "route",
        title: "My route",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
   {
        category: "story",
        title: "My story",
        location: "Mexico",
        text: "....",
      },
    ],
  },
]

let storiesWithCategoryCardCount = data.reduce((res, curr) => {
  let storyCardCount = curr.stories.filter(story => story.category === 'card').length;
  return res + storyCardCount;
}, 0)

console.log(storiesWithCategoryCardCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there could be more cards with the `'card'` category in the `'stories'` array item, try this approach:

```
let numOfCards = data.reduce((acc, dItem:any) => {
   let items = dItem.stories?.filter((story: any) => story.category === 'card').length; 
   return acc + items;
}, 0);
```

Comment: I'd recommend removing typescript syntax from this answer to avoid confusion. OP is asking about JS